# setting progress to progress bar while downloading a file

Tags: android, pdf, download, progressdialog, progress

i am developing an app in which a user can read pdf books online/offline. If he has pdf reader installed then the book gets downloaded from the server and gets opened in that pdf reader but if he don't have a pdf reader installed then in that case pdf is opened online(using google docs link).

Now, when downloading a pdf file i want to display a progress dialog to the user but don't know how to set the percentage of file being downloaded ..I've searched for this but all the solutions given are for http connection.In my case it would be in a different manner i guess. So kindly check my code and then suggest me a way to do so. Thanks in advance.

**PDFtools.java**

```
public class PDFtools {
    static Context mContext;
     public PDFtools(Context mContext) {
           PDFtools.mContext = mContext;
     }

    private static final String GOOGLE_DRIVE_PDF_READER_PREFIX = "http://drive.google.com/viewer?url=";
    private static final String PDF_MIME_TYPE = "application/pdf";
    private static final String HTML_MIME_TYPE = "text/html";

    /**
     * If a PDF reader is installed, download the PDF file and open it in a reader. 
     * Otherwise ask the user if he/she wants to view it in the Google Drive online PDF reader.<br />
     * <br />
     * <b>BEWARE:</b> This method
     * @param context
     * @param pdfUrl
     * @return
     */


    public static void showPDFUrl( final Context context, final String pdfUrl ) {
        if ( isPDFSupported( context ) ) {
            downloadAndOpenPDF(context, pdfUrl);
        } else {
            askToOpenPDFThroughGoogleDrive( context, pdfUrl );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Downloads a PDF with the Android DownloadManager and opens it with an installed PDF reader app.
     * @param context
     * @param pdfUrl
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    public static void downloadAndOpenPDF(final Context context, final String pdfUrl) {
        // Get filename
        final String filename = pdfUrl.substring( pdfUrl.lastIndexOf( "/" ) + 1 );
        // The place where the downloaded PDF file will be put
        final File tempFile = new File( context.getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ), filename );
        if ( tempFile.exists() ) {
            // If we have downloaded the file before, just go ahead and show it.
            openPDF( context, Uri.fromFile( tempFile ) );
            return;
        }


        // Show progress dialog while downloading
        final ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show( context, context.getString( R.string.pdf_show_local_progress_title ), context.getString( R.string.pdf_show_local_progress_title), true );

        // Create the download request
        DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request( Uri.parse( pdfUrl ) );
        r.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir( context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename );

        final DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService( Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE );

        BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if ( !progress.isShowing() ) {
                    return;
                }

                context.unregisterReceiver( this );

                progress.dismiss();
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra( DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1 );
                Cursor c = dm.query( new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById( downloadId ) );

                if ( c.moveToFirst() ) {
                    int status = c.getInt( c.getColumnIndex( DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS ) );
                    if ( status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL ) {
                        openPDF( context, Uri.fromFile( tempFile ) );
                    }
                }
                c.close();
            }
        };
        context.registerReceiver( onComplete, new IntentFilter( DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE ) );

        // Enqueue the request
        dm.enqueue( r );
    }


    /**
     * Show a dialog asking the user if he wants to open the PDF through Google Drive
     * @param context
     * @param pdfUrl
     */
    public static void askToOpenPDFThroughGoogleDrive( final Context context, final String pdfUrl ) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder( context )
            .setTitle("PDF reader not installed!")
            .setMessage( "Do you want to open it with Google Drive ?" )
            .setNegativeButton( "No", null )
            .setPositiveButton( "Yes", new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    openPDFThroughGoogleDrive(context, pdfUrl); 
                }
            })
            .show();
    }

    /**
     * Launches a browser to view the PDF through Google Drive
     * @param context
     * @param pdfUrl
     */
    public static void openPDFThroughGoogleDrive(final Context context, final String pdfUrl) {
        Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(GOOGLE_DRIVE_PDF_READER_PREFIX + pdfUrl ), HTML_MIME_TYPE );
        context.startActivity( i );
    }
    /**
     * Open a local PDF file with an installed reader
     * @param context
     * @param localUri
     */
    public static final void openPDF(Context context, Uri localUri ) {
        Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        i.setDataAndType( localUri, PDF_MIME_TYPE );
        context.startActivity( i );
    }
    /**
     * Checks if any apps are installed that supports reading of PDF files.
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isPDFSupported( Context context ) {
        Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        final File tempFile = new File( context.getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ), "test.pdf" );
        i.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( tempFile ), PDF_MIME_TYPE );
        return context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY ).size() > 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could simply use Aysnctask with mch ease

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by performing a query to the download manager.
It's pretty straightforward, you probably want to query for the columns 
`COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR` and `COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES`.

After getting those numbers you should set the actual progress in the progress bar by calling `ProgressDialog.setProgress`.

An example of how to make the query can be found [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java#L76-L100)

Comment: I am a beginner in android so kindly give me a proper code to do so..then i will accept it as the answer, thank you.

Comment: As I said, you can found a working example [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java#L76-L100). Good luck